# Not able to dispatch request in spring from one controller to another controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dispatcher

I have dispatched my request from one controller to another controller using requestdispatcher but when it runs it goes into basictilesdef and gives me error
This is source controller code

```
public ModelAndView forwardRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception 
{
    //String urlToForward=httpServletRequest.getParameter("urlToForward");
    httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("postQuery.htm?actionCode=answerQuery%26queryListStatus=ANS%26strKey=90302140000326").forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();      
    return new ModelAndView("homePage", "loginForm", loginForm);
}
```

error I got is

```
03/02/2014 20:34:07 ERROR PortalExceptionResolver:43] Exception ID (MESSAGE_KEY) : 1391439847740 : Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: postQuery
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: postQuery
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor289.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:151)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:282)
    at $Proxy34.forward(Unknown Source)
    at com.tcs.kra.tps.portal.controller.common.MainController.forwardRequest(MainController.java:1255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:473)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:203)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: postQuery
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:578)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:257)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:902)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
postQuery.htm
```

See Caused by error is Tiles definition not declared in your Tiles.xml (apache tiles configuration file ) 
Ref: [struts 2 tiles NoSuchDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770344/struts-2-tiles-nosuchdefinitionexception)
i think you have to check your tiles definition

Comment: But here i am forwarding my request to another controller so why would i need to give tile defination for tha?

Comment: Yes @keval but caused by Error denote this error is because of Tiles definition